# Text background color and custom footer in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, footer

I have 2 questions about wordpress:

I am working on a website and need to add a background color to the  title that continues on the left en right of the text. This is how it looks like with a normal background color:

[image]
This is what I need:

[image]
The second question: I need a footer that disappears and reappears if you click on the red footer (see picture 2). Anybody code/plugin that I can use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please ask such questions in the [Wordpress support forums](http://wordpress.org/support/). Thank you!

Comment: You are using a theme or developing your own child theme?

You can achieve first solution by adding proper css to your style file and the footer problem can be solved using jQuery, you have to use onclick event properly to hide or show footer.

Provide a link to your website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS as the answer for question 1. Try using padding so that there is space around your text. Here is a sample:

```
p.padding
{
padding-top:25px;
padding-bottom:25px;
padding-right:50px;
padding-left:50px;
}
```

This will add padding around your paragraph and you will be able to achieve what you asked for in question 1. Unfortunately, I cannot answer Q2 as usually there are a few plugins that you can use in Wordpress. I would recomend one that I have used [SocialToolbarPro](http://socialtoolbarpro.com/) . It is paid but the free version is just as good if you know what you are doing :)

Hope this helps